# are ejb and jars subdeployments in an EAR

Tags: java, jboss, slf4j, logback

I've been having problems with jboss/logback and I made a jboss-deployment-structure.xml and it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
            some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>


    </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

this is in the META-INF folder of the EAR, but now I've been thinking...  the EAR also has a lib folder that has:

slf4j-api.jar,

logback-classic.jar,

logback-core.jar, and

log4j-over-slf4j.jar

as well as the other two other ejb projects wrapped up in it during deployment time.

my question is, do I have to specify the jars and other other ejb projects as sub-deployments in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml??

also, the jboss-deployment-structure.xml has been basically ignored everytime I deploy the ear and start the server, i know this because the server still is accessing the exclusions i have declared, is the xml in the right spot in the meta-inf of the ear?

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes I added the jars as subdeployments and fixed errors